# How to invoke a method on a managed bean when pressing backbutton or F5?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-1.2

How can I invoke a method on a managed bean when pressing backbutton or F5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bean is request scoped and the page is served with response headers which instructs the browser to [not cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301530/jsf-how-to-force-hard-reload-of-current-page) the page, then you can do that job in the bean's constructor or `@PostConstruct` method.

E.g.

```
public class Bean {

    public Bean() {
        // Here, in the constructor.
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Or here, in the postconstructor.
    }

}
```

The `@PostConstruct` method is particularly useful if you're injecting dependencies by  `@ManagedProperty`, `@EJB` or `@Inject`, etc and want to do the initialization job based on those dependencies.

Comment: sorry but i didnt understand your answer, can u be more specific

Comment: Put the code in constructor of the bean, or a method which has the `@PostConstruct` annotation. Further you need to make sure that JSF requests are not cached by the browser. You can do that with a `Filter`.